# How can I debug "The default Firebase app has not yet been configured."?

Tags: swift, firebase, push-notification

It looks like I'm getting the error message "The default Firebase app has not yet been configured" from my call to FirebaseApp.configure(); here's my code:

```
  func configPushNotifications() {
    NSLog("\(TAG) in configPushNotifications")
    FirebaseApp.configure()
    NSLog("\(TAG) called FirebaseApp.configure()")
    Messaging.messaging().delegate = self
    NSLog("\(TAG) set msg'ing delegate")
    if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
      UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self
      let authOptions: UNAuthorizationOptions = [.alert, .badge, .sound]
      UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(
        options: authOptions,
        completionHandler: {_, _ in })
    }
    UIApplication.shared.registerForRemoteNotifications()
    NSLog("\(TAG) called registerForRemoteNotifications")
  }
```

... and the resulting log:

```
2019-12-02 16:28:27.375255-0500 rMove[541:62736] _PH_ in configPushNotifications
2019-12-02 16:28:27.398807-0500 rMove[541:62982] 6.10.0 - [Firebase/Core][I-COR000003] The default Firebase app has not yet been configured. Add `[FIRApp configure];` (`FirebaseApp.configure()` in Swift) to your application initialization. Read more: [shortened URL here].
2019-12-02 16:28:27.403226-0500 rMove[541:62982] 6.10.0 - [Firebase/Core][I-COR000003] The default Firebase app has not yet been configured. Add `[FIRApp configure];` (`FirebaseApp.configure()` in Swift) to your application initialization. Read more: [shortened URL here].
2019-12-02 16:28:27.420648-0500 rMove[541:62982] 6.10.0 - [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS024000] Debug mode is on
2019-12-02 16:28:27.469885-0500 rMove[541:62982] 6.10.0 - [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS005000] The AdSupport Framework is not currently linked. Some features will not function properly. Learn more at [shortened URL here]
2019-12-02 16:28:27.472623-0500 rMove[541:62982] 6.10.0 - [GoogleUtilities/AppDelegateSwizzler][I-SWZ001008] Successfully created App Delegate Proxy automatically. To disable the proxy, set the flag GoogleUtilitiesAppDelegateProxyEnabled to NO (Boolean) in the Info.plist
2019-12-02 16:28:27.474543-0500 rMove[541:62982] 6.10.0 - [Firebase/Messaging][I-FCM002000] FIRMessaging library version 4.1.9
2019-12-02 16:28:27.475493-0500 rMove[541:62982] 6.10.0 - [GULReachability][I-REA902003] Monitoring the network status
2019-12-02 16:28:27.476105-0500 rMove[541:62982] 6.10.0 - [GULReachability][I-REA902003] Monitoring the network status
2019-12-02 16:28:27.476841-0500 rMove[541:62982] 6.10.0 - [Firebase/Messaging][I-FCM001000] FIRMessaging Remote Notifications proxy enabled, will swizzle remote notification receiver handlers. If you'd prefer to manually integrate Firebase Messaging, add "FirebaseAppDelegateProxyEnabled" to your Info.plist, and set it to NO. Follow the instructions at:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/ios/client#method_swizzling_in_firebase_messaging
to ensure proper integration.
2019-12-02 16:28:27.479696-0500 rMove[541:62736] _PH_ called FirebaseApp.configure()
2019-12-02 16:28:27.481380-0500 rMove[541:62736] _PH_ set msg'ing delegate
2019-12-02 16:28:27.526128-0500 rMove[541:63008] 6.10.0 - [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS023007] Analytics v.60103000 started
2019-12-02 16:28:27.527311-0500 rMove[541:63008] 6.10.0 - [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS023008] To disable debug logging set the following application argument: -noFIRAnalyticsDebugEnabled (see [shortened URL here])
2019-12-02 16:28:27.529499-0500 rMove[541:63008] 6.10.0 - [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS023009] Debug logging enabled
2019-12-02 16:28:27.533081-0500 rMove[541:62736] _PH_ called registerForRemoteNotifications
```

This is a new version of my app, and I haven't modified this code from the working version. How can I debug this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Xcode's debugger, I found that Firebase Messaging, which is in the FirebaseApp.configure() call stack, was trying to access the default Firebase app before FirebaseApp.configure() set it. Setting the value of FirebaseMessagingAutoInitEnabled in an *-Info.plist worked around this issue; the plist values were checked for this before the default app.

Comment: setting it to false or to true ??